# I am getting a HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Looked int other posts of "Servlet.init() for servlet " didnt help.
 This is not a Maven or Gradle, so no pom.This is a plain simple spring project, which I am still struggling with. Below the snippets is the actuall error.

Hellocontroller.java.

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.*;

//import com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange.Map;

public class Hellocontroller implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

           String name = req.getParameter("name");

           Map m = new HashMap();
           m.put("msg", "Hello ...."+name);                             

           ModelAndView mav =new ModelAndView("success",m);

        return mav;
    }

}
```

HelloWorld-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



    <bean name="./hello.ds" class="controller.Hellocontroller">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ds</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

success.jsp

```
${msg}
```

index.jsp

```
<h1>HelloWorld</h1>

<form action ="./hello.ds">

NAME:<input type = "text" name="name">

SUBMIT<input type = "submit" value="sayHello">


</form>
```

Errors:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWorld-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalViewResolver
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:570)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1277
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your configuration. The class `org.springframework.web.servlet.InternalViewResolver` doesn't exist (could it be you copy/pasted this from an ancient spring mvc example?).

Try replacing it with `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`. I cannot guarantee it works, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Just did that and Im getting a HTTP Status 404 -  requested resource is not available

Comment: The problem is that you're not mapping the controller to the URL. I would suggest you to find another example. If I'm not mistaken you're following an example for Spring 2.5 (or older) which is very, very old. Try to find a Spring 4 tutorial: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=spring+4+mvc+tutorial&t=ffsb&ia=web  (spring has moved forward a lot since then)

Comment: You mean the front controller?.can you give me the LOC

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I haven't touched spring 2.5 in about 7 years... I know that the mapping was done manually back then, but I cannot remember how to do it. Again, what you're learning now won't be of any use unless you work on an old application that hasn't been maintained for many years.

Comment: @ Fine. Had a look at the link you have given. Thanks, and no offence but it is slightly misleading, and this proj is not 2.5, its the 3rd version.